# How to conver an ES2.0 shader into WebGL using ThreeJS

Tags: three.js, glsl, webgl, fragment-shader, vertex-shader

#### The Goal

I'm attempting to convert a shader written in an Android friendly GLES20 syntax to something that will work with the likes of threeJS.

Most of the uniforms for the fragment shader are straightforward but I have a lot of confusion around how the the vertex shaders gl_position should be calculated.

#### So Far

Here I have an example of a simple plane maps a texture and takes a single uniform, nothing fancy, and attempts to render the texture.

However android ES has some default values passed into its shaders,
as does threeJS. I'd like to find out which of these are corresponding to eachother.

```
<script id="androidEsVertexShader" type="x-shader/x-vertex">
  attribute vec4 position;
  precision mediump float;

  uniform mat4 camTextureTransform;
  attribute vec4 camTexCoordinate;
  varying vec2 v_CamTexCoordinate;

  void main()
  {
      v_CamTexCoordinate = (camTextureTransform * camTexCoordinate).xy;
      gl_Position = position;
  }
</script>
```

Conversion attempt to ThreeJS

```
<script id="threeJsVertexShader" type="x-shader/x-vertex">
  varying vec2 v_CamTexCoordinate;
  void main()
  {
      v_CamTexCoordinate = uv;
      gl_Position = projectionMatrix * modelViewMatrix * vec4( position, 1.0 );
  }
</script>
```

A list of the values passed into ThreeJS vertex shaders and subsequent fragshaders.
https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/renderers/webgl/WebGLProgram

Full codepen example showing a doggo as a completely gray image.
https://codepen.io/shanethmoore/pen/OJOLrEv

Comment: Yes, you need matrix multiplications. [This is how Three.js handles them in the vertex shader](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/464a5f0381924cb7448f8f51cd8ffe1ee0dc243d/src/renderers/shaders/ShaderChunk/default_vertex.glsl.js)

Comment: @Marquizzo Thank you for the comment! While reading the documentatin about built in uniforms and attributes for threeJS, I see it actually suggests the same as the code you supplied. So you're 100% right on how gl_position is suggested to be calculated. However I'm still confused about the parity between the android ES attributes. In my example I am assigning v_CamTexCoordinate to uv. And I assume that camTextureTransform maps to viewMatrix and camTexCoordinate maps to position.xyz. I'm obviously wrong or my codepen wouldn't be showing a gray blur.

Comment: Simply put, I'm trying to understand which vertex attributes/uniforms for the android ES map to which values in the built in threeJS attributes. Assuming they have a 1:1 mapping

Comment: Your code looks fine. The problem is that you're looking at a plane that's 800 units wide at a distance of 10 units, so of course you're gonna see only one pixel at a time. Make your plane 20x20, and keep the position.x at 0, and you'll see more of your texture.

Comment: You are exactly right, the vertex shader was passing through fine and the problem was the distance to the plane.

If you want to add an answer explaining the logic behind that in more detail I'd be happy to accept